# Belkin Wireless Adapter Card F9L1101V2 not Working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04

So I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my desktop. However, the system does not have the driver for my wireless card (Belkin F9L1101V2). Does anyone have similiar problem? Any help is appreciated.

To follow up with wildman's comment.

Here is the result I got after running the script:

Thank you!

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux DJ-Ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 and other motherboards [1043:8432]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #####

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f2:0116 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-2971/KU-0325 Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 050d:110a Belkin Components 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #####

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

No way to aquire root rights found.

##### iwlist channel #####

##### lsmod #####

##### modinfo #####

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #####

########## wireless info END ########
```

#### #

Comment: There are some people who have made it work...  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176114

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by following the advice Wild Man gave you. Thank you!

Comment: @WildMan, I have added the info to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled this driver on my computer and it compiled with no errors or warnings.

Do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du.git
cd rtl8192du
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

When you have an upgrade to the kernel you will have to do:

```
cd rtl8192du
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot
Original directions are from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12688576#post12688576) courtesy of chili555.

Install driver without internet connection:

Download the driver [rtl8192du](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du/archive/master.zip) to a flash drive then drag it to your ubuntu desktop, right click and choose extract here:

```
cd Desktop/rtl8192du-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

When there is a kernel upgrade you will have to do:

```
cd rtl8192du
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. The problem is I do not have internet on my desktop now. My laptop has internet, Is there a way to do it without internet? Thanks!

Comment: I added directions for installing the driver without an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I packaged that driver to ppa in DKMS format. It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192du-dkms
```