# Belkin Wireless USB F9L1101v2 incompatible w/ 14.04?

Tags: wireless, networking

Hey all and thank you for reading. I followed this guide: [belkinf9l1101v2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485292/belkin-wireless-adapter-card-f9l1101v2-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04)

and I can't seem to get it working on my system like this user was able to. Everything actually works properly up until the "make" command is executed: [Error pastey](http://pastebin.com/duL6aid8)

If anyone has any ideas why this would happen I would love to figure out how to fix it! This is a freshly installed system. Any other information needed can be provided :)

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try this version instead. I just tried it and it makes perfectly on my 3.13.0-32 install: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du/archive/kernel-version.zip The instructions are the same after you download the correct version.

Comment: It worked flawlessly! Thank you very much for your help. Although I don't really understand what was different, I am very happy it worked. I am posting from the machine now :)