# Belkin f9L1101v2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

as the title describes I am trying to get a belking f9L1101v2 to run on my laptop that is running Ubuntu 14.04. I have followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485292/belkin-wireless-adapter-card-f9l1101v2-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04) but I get an error when typing "make"

```
 mike@mikes-first-computer:~/Desktop/rtl8192du-master$ make
 make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/build M=/home
 /mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master  modules
 make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic'
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_cmd.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_security.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_debug.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_io.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_mlme.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_rf.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_recv.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_ap.o
 CC [M]  /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_xmit.o
 /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_xmit.c: In function ‘update_attrib’:
 /home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_xmit.c:441:2: error: implicit 
 declaration of function ‘ether_addr_copy’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 ether_addr_copy(pattrib->dst, ehdr->h_dest);
 ^
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 make[2]: *** [/home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master/core/rtw_xmit.o] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mike/Desktop/rtl8192du-master] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic'
 make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

So then of course "sudo make install" doesn't work.

I am really lost on what to do so could someone please help me?

Thank you,
Tyler

EDIT:
I just ran the wireless script found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and got

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 22 Dec 2014 14:00 EST -0500

Booted last: 21 Dec 2014 00:36 EST -0500

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354] (rev 13)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02aa]
Kernel driver in use: sky2

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 011: ID 050d:110a Belkin Components 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

r8712u                184158  0 
b43                   387371  0 
dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
bcma                   52096  1 b43
mac80211              630653  1 b43
dell_laptop            18168  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
cfg80211              484040  2 b43,mac80211
wmi                    19177  1 dell_wmi
ssb                    62379  1 b43

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
      inet addr:192.168.1.34  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::223:aeff:fe32:bed1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:165527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:105619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:199560507 (199.5 MB)  TX bytes:9805257 (9.8 MB)
      Interrupt:18 

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search westell.com

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            sky2
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.34
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=F5TD9
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/09FX01025569]] (600 root)
[connection] id=09FX01025569 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=09FX01025569 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[r8712u]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8712/r8712u.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin
author:         Larry Finger
description:    rtl871x wireless lan driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     5A7B13CC2FA1D2F4B5820F9
depends:        
staging:        Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           wifi_test:int
parm:           video_mode:int
parm:           chip_version:int
parm:           rfintfs:int
parm:           lbkmode:int
parm:           hci:int
parm:           network_mode:int
parm:           channel:int
parm:           mp_mode:int
parm:           wmm_enable:int
parm:           vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           vcs_type:int
parm:           busy_thresh:int
parm:           ht_enable:int
parm:           cbw40_enable:int
parm:           ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rf_config:int
parm:           power_mgnt:int
parm:           low_power:int
parm:           ifname: Net interface name, wlan%d=default (string)
parm:           initmac:MAC-Address, default: use FUSE (charp)

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     7ABBDDCA84C087640B27AE6
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     E41B811D88783DD5BC38565
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     446B3604A9C5461044DD691
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C2478077E22138832B71659
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     3DE188310F77C566C2E8CB3
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

[r8712u]
ampdu_enable: 1
busy_thresh: 40
cbw40_enable: 1
channel: 1
chip_version: 2
hci: 1
ht_enable: 1
ifname: wlan%d
initmac: (null)
lbkmode: 0
low_power: 0
mp_mode: 0
network_mode: 0
power_mgnt: 0
rf_config: 1
rfintfs: 2
vcs_type: 1
video_mode: 1
vrtl_carrier_sense: 2
wifi_test: 0
wmm_enable: 0

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x11ab:0x4354 (sky2)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (r8712u)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [revision 85a2b460d46687d19eb1ae61d806a89ee107f5bb](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du/commit/85a2b460d46687d19eb1ae61d806a89ee107f5bb#diff-0) the driver started to use `ether_addr_copy`, which was introduced only in the Linux kernel v3.14, but Ubuntu Tursty uses v3.13. You can either

1. upgrade your kernel,

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
   ```

   Advantages:

   - Allows you to keep the newest version of the rtl8192du module.
   - May solve some other (hardware/driver) problems.

   Disadvantages:

   - May be incompatible with other hardware (in rare cases) or OS components (not so rare unfortunately). You can install both kernel versions side by side, try out the newer one and switch back to another easily, if you experience problems.
   - Not entirely trivial.
2. or downgrade the driver to a prior revision.

   ```
   make clean
   git reset --hard
   git checkout 85a2b460d46687d19eb1ae61d806a89ee107f5bb^
   ```

   Advantages:

   - Almost trivial to perform.

   Disadvantages:

   - May expose bugs in the driver that were fixed since then.

Comment: so the first one is upgrading to 14.10? I think that is what I am going to do thank you! I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Not really. You can upgrade the kernel to that of Utopic while otherwise retaining Trusty. A full upgrade would solve the problem too of course.