# Belkin F9L1101V2 wireless will not install on Ubuntu 14,04 LTS

Tags: wireless

Hello all I read the post here: [Belkin Wireless Adapter Card F9L1101V2 not Working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485292/belkin-wireless-adapter-card-f9l1101v2-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04)

And posted there, but was redirected to post on here.

please excuse my ignorance on this matter as I am very new to dealing with computer software; However, I too have just installed Ubuntu 14,04 LTS and I too have a belkin f9l1101v2 that will not work because of the driver and I don't have the internet either.

So I downloaded Wild Mans compressed driver onto a flash drive and extracted it onto my desktop, and the folder is there with all the files but my wireless adapter still is not working.

So I went into the terminal and typed the instructed codes:

cd Desktop/rtl8192du-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du

when I get to the sudo make install it asks for a password, but will not let me type a password,

So I am stuck here

I have never used Ubuntu before but I like it so far. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the password is not echoed, not even ******. Please just type it in and press Enter. If it is mis-typed you will be told. If not, the command will be executed as is.